# There are some simple questions about my JS.please heip me

Tags: javascript

This is my js's code(I am chinese and not so good at English) computer said that "window is not defined". But it's same as the code in book(JavaScript DOM),so why?

```js
function addLoadEvent(func) {
  var oldonload = window.onload;
  if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
    window.onload = func;
  } else {
    window.onload = function() {
      oldonload();
      func();
    }
  }
}

function insertAfter(newElement, targetElement) {
  var parent = targetElement.parentNode;
  if (parent.lastChild == targetElement) {
    parent.appendChild(newElement);
  } else {
    parent.insertBefore(newElement, targetElement.nextSibling);
  }
}

function preparePlaceholder() {
  if (!document.createElement) return false;
  if (!document.createTextNode) return false;
  if (!document.getElementById) return false;
  if (!document.getElementById("imagegallery")) return false;
  var placeholder = document.createElement("img");
  placeholder.setAttribute("id", "placeholder");
  placeholder.setAttribute("src", "images/placeholder.jpg");
  placeholder.setAttribute("alt", "my image gallery");
  var description = document.createElement("p");
  description.setAttribute("id", "description");
  var desctext = document.createTextNode("Choose an image");
  description.appendChild(desctext);
  var gallery = document.getElementById("imagegallery");
  insertAfter(placeholder, gallery);
  insertAfter(description, placeholder);
}

function prepareGallery() {
  if (!document.getElementsByTagName) return false;
  if (!document.getElementById) return false;
  if (!document.getElementById("imagegallery")) return false;
  var gallery = document.getElementById("imagegallery");
  var links = gallery.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].onclick = function() {
      return showPic(this);
    }
    links[i].onkeypress = links[i].onclick;
  }
}


function showPic(whichpic) {
  if (!document.getElementById("placeholder")) return true;
  var source = whichpic.getAttribute("href");
  var placeholder = document.getElementById("palceholder");
  placeholder.setAttribute("src", source);
  if (!document.getElementById("description")) return false;
  if (whichpic.getAttribute("title")) {
    var text = whichpic.getAttribute("title");
  } else {
    var text = "";
  }
  var description = document.getElementById("description");
  if (description.firstChild.nodeType == 3) {
    description.firstChild.nodeValue = text;
  }
  return false;
}
addLoadEvent(preparePlaceholder);
addLoadEvent(prepareGallery);
```

and when i do addLoadEvent(prepareGallery); it said "Function lack of objects"..why? it's also same as the code in book.please help me.

Comment: Where/how are you running this code?

Comment: Window is global object in any web browser, so as long as you execute that code in it you are fine and window will be defined. However if you are running it in node.js window will be undefined.

Comment: I run it in wiondow,wirte it by TXT,save it to js.but it can't work,show" window is not defined "....OMG,why?

Comment: if there is something wrong with my computer system?  i just downloaded the modernize-custom.js . but when i double clicked it , system said:'window is not defined' ..what's the wrong.......